# Using analytical db with Looker and Big query

Tags: google-bigquery, looker

Does transactional database which is migrated to analytical to use with Bigquery and eventually Looker, need to be denormalized for faster queries and higher concurrency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can say "yes", here is the best practice recommended by google. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input#denormalizing_data